# How to simultaneously substitute all the identical words in online code editor of interviewbit?

Tags: text-editor, multicursorediting

#### Can you suggest some keyboard shortcut to substitute several occurrences of a word with some other word in a code editor!

Eg: In the picture below, I want to convert all the occurrences of 'int' to 'long int'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For sublime text editor use **Alt + F3**